# Unweighted vs Weighted sample

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a classification task that I perform using DNN.

Whenever I use a weighted training sample, I get an inverted ROC curve, which is not the case with unweighted sample.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, input_dim=25, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation=tf.nn.relu),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, 
['accuracy'],sample_weight_mode= None)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50,validation_split=0.3, 
batch_size=250,verbose=0, sample_weight = weight_train)
```

#### Weighted ROC

[image: weightedROC]

#### Unweighted ROC

[image: unWeightedROC]

Comment: Updated text for clarity and added inline images.  Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's nice, but you failed to ask a question.

Comment: My question is what could be the cause of ROC curve to get overturned when I train the model using the weights (sample weights)? Whenever I don't take the weights into consideration I then get perfect curve

Comment: Oh, I got it. The weights had a combination of negative and positive numbers in the data. I then took the min-max for normalization and it worked just fine.